# Making excel graphs appear/disappear

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, graph

I want a graph only to appear when a condition is fulfilled. To be more precise: I have a drop down menu that changes the content of a graph. If the menu point "Total revenue" is clicked, I want a second graph to appear. I am new to VBA and this is what I came up with so far:

```
Sub Iffuntion()
Dim SelectedChart As Range
Dim notVisible As Boolean
If Range("D100").Value = Range("E100").Value Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Testchart").Visible = True
Else
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Testchart").Visible = notVisible
End If
End Sub
```

It works, but I have to execute the VBA to make the graph appear/disappear and I would like that to happen automatically. Also the condition should eventually be in another worksheet to keep the sheet with the graphs nice and tidy. I read that to achieve this I have toI have to activate the other worksheet. Would you recommend this way or is there a better solution?

Thanks for the help and best regards!
Pete

EDIT: Here is the link to a sample file with the proposed solution of Cor_Blimey, that I couldn't get to work properly. The interconnections in the excel are more complicated than they would have to be, but I wanted to be as accurate ad possible in displaying what is actually happening in my excel. Thanks for taking a look!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18406645/sample.xlsm

Comment: What type of drop-down do you have? A form control or ActiveX? When do you want this code to run? I do not know what you mean by a "menu point".

Comment: `Worksheet.Change` event is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Andy! It is a Form Control drop down menu. By menu point I mean one of the options you can chose in the drop down menu.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make Cor_Blimeys code work. I posted a sample file above. Is there anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that they change, from a data validation drop down list, the contents of a cell then you can put your code into the Worksheet's Worksheet_Change event. This event is fired when the user changes the content of a cell (or by an external link).

Then test for the cell being the right cell then run your code.

Like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D100"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If rng.Value = Me.Range("E100").Value Then
            Me.ChartObjects("Testchart").Visible = True
        Else
            Me.ChartObjects("Testchart").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A long way to `ChartObjects("Testchart").Visible=Range("E100").Value`! I know you're preventing changes in other cells triggering code. But you should be aware that changes to multiple cells can occur, so `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E100")) Is Nothing Then` would be broader.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Cor_Blimey, and thanks to everyone else. I tried your code but I don't know how to tell the program in which external workbook to look. I created a sample file to display my problem. I only want to display Table4 when Table3 is displayed, as you will see in the excel. Thanks a lot for the help!